# Is there any reason to freeze an object other than an array or an explicit "object"

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I understand why one would use `Object.freeze()` on an array or object, as it prevents shallow modification to anything contained within it, but is there any reason to use it on something else? A Boolean, String, RegExp, Number, a custom class?

Specifically, I am wondering about anonymous functions, although anything I learn here will probably be of use to me somewhere along my road.

Answer (score -1):

It is not good to do it with classes because Classes must be mutable objects to modify its attributes and in some cases their states. But it can be a good approach to do it if you are just passing that value to a deep nested function. But this method does not affect primitive types, you can try

```js
let value = Object.freeze(true)
value = false
console.log(value) // Output => false
```

You will see that this does not produce any error, so there is no good reason to use it with primitives.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Comment: As functions are not "primitives," would it be effective in any way?

Comment: @red Yes, you can use with object to make them immutable with that the runtime will notify that you are trying to modify a freezed object.

Comment: Are there any properties that you know of that can be changed on a function?